# Placeholders in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataset where different values can only be classified by the occurrence of the digit `1`. All values consist of 5 digits. Now I need to create a new variable that groups the values. My question now is, whether there is a way similiar to Excel to set placeholders in order to identify those values that start with `1`.

What I have done so far is:

> w$r <- ifelse(w$f == 1****, 1, 0)

Here, I wanted to filter out all values where `1` is the first digit.
It is noteworthy that some values have a reoccuring `1`, i.e. on 2 digits.
All variables have either a 1 in them or are zero. 
Examples for data are 00000, 00001, 11100 etc. The goal is to create a variable for every 1 at a different position. E.g. First digit one should be a variable, but also a variable were the 1 occurs as the first and third digit needs to be accounted for in the created variable 1 and variable 3.

Comment: Have a look at `stringr::str_locate`

Comment: Not sure if I understood you completely, Let me know if below works for you.   `grepl('^1\\d{4}$', input)+0`,  where `input <- c('18908','20834','10982')`

Comment: Sample data might be useful.

Comment: I clarified the task in the question. And added examples. Hope it is clearer now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Amy See the edit to my answer. Is this what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**:

Not quite sure whether that's what you want, but here's a try:

**Data**:

Since you also seem to have data with leading zeros you need to convert them to character:

```
df <- data.frame(w = c("00000", "00001", "11100", "10010", "11000", "10000", "10100", "00100", "10001"))
```

**Solution**:

```
# variable for "1" in first position:
df$r1 <- ifelse(grepl("^1", df$w), 1, 0)

# variable for "1" in second position:
df$r2 <- ifelse(grepl("^\\d1", df$w), 1, 0)

# variable for "1" in third position:
df$r3 <- ifelse(grepl("^\\d{2}1", df$w), 1, 0)

# variable for "1" in fourth position:
df$r4 <- ifelse(grepl("^\\d{3}1", df$w), 1, 0)

# variable for "1" in fifth position:
df$r5 <- ifelse(grepl("^\\d{4}1", df$w), 1, 0)
```

**Result**:

```
df
      w r r2 r3 r4
1 00000 0  0  0  0
2 00001 0  0  0  1
3 11100 1  1  1  0
4 10010 1  0  0  0
5 11000 1  1  0  0
6 10000 1  0  0  0
7 10100 1  0  1  0
8 00100 0  0  1  0
9 10001 1  0  0  1
```

Comment: Actually, it is quite different the data is more like 10010, 11000, 10000 etc. and i need to create 5 variables. One variable for all variables starting with1. Another variables for all variables where 1 is the 2nd digit.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked out  flawlessly!